# Model validation, validate a string is an integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

Hi I have a model called users, and they have a cell phone attribute that must be entered as a 12 digit string leading with "+". I want to validate that the attribute they entered from a form is in fact in the correct format. Example "+11234567890" should save to the model, but "1232h" will not.

This is what I have in my model, but it does not work:

```
  validates :cell, :format => { :with => /^[-+]?[0-9]+$/,
    :message => "Only numbers allowed" }, :length => { :is => 10 }
```

Comment: What happens if you use this for your regular expression: `/\A[0-9]+\z/`? Also, note that your regex allows 10 or 11 letters, but you are enforcing 10.

Comment: Thanks, also I just edited again, I need to check that the string is in the format of "+11234567890"

Comment: Did you try my suggestion for the regex string? I understand what you're trying to match. Also, you still need to allow for 11 characters if they use a `+` or `-`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it did not work. I was still able to save "dfds" into the db

Comment: It allows numbers to get through, but they can be any length

Comment: I think I can use this validation, but I also need to check that the string starts with "+1" and then includes the 10 digit phone number.

Comment: Try the one in my answer. It allows a 10 digit phone with optional +1 in front.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
validates :cell, :format => { :with => /\A(\+1)?[0-9]{10}\z/, :message => "Not a valid 10-digit telephone number" }
```

I think the problem is that you're trying to do two different kinds of validations on a single `validates` line. The above combines the length constraint with the number constraint, and allows the variable +/- without messing up the length constraint.

Comment: It works! Thank you, only problem was you forgot the extra digit after +. So I changed it to 11, instead of 10. Thank you!

Comment: Careful: the (\+1) should capture the +1 independent of the 10 digits of the number (unless I'm counting my digits wrong). You might also want to check out Rails helpers `number_to_phone` and `telephone_field` if you're interested in more specific phone number formatting.